# Affect this in a variable instead of using the fat arrow in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, this, arrow-functions

What is the difference between using the fat arrow (bind the function to the current value of this), and putting the value of @ in a variable?

Fat arrow

```
Account = (customer, cart) ->
  @customer = customer
  @cart = cart

  $('.shopping_cart').bind 'click', (event) =>
    @customer.purchase @cart
```

and

```
Account = (customer, cart) ->
  @customer = customer
  @cart = cart

  self = @
  $('.shopping_cart').bind 'click', (event) ->
    self.customer.purchase self.cart
```

[@](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/49894) suggests that using the fat arrow avoid cluttering up the surrounding scope. How?

Comment: Obviously, using an arrow function is a lot lighter.

Comment: Arrow instead of fat arrow? What is the benefit of the fat arrow then?

Comment: Bergi meant the fat arrow, which by the way is implemented with something similar to `this_ = this`. Think of fat arrow as a shortcut.

Comment: If you look at the compiled code, the fat arrow translates to a function wrapping the original function, and bound to `@`. It is different than the second solution `self = @`.

Comment: Different implementation (and different depending on your CoffeeScript version too) but the same functionality. What exactly is the question here? And you shouldn't say "seems slower", you should benchmark it with multiple JavaScript engines and work with facts.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the behavior is different in different versions of CoffeeScript, which makes my question even more relevant. I read that having two functions instead of one is slower  (for example [here](http://michaeljosephkramer.com/2013/03/12/the-simplified-fat-arrow-guide-for-coffeescript/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I benchmarked your two snippets along with two other fat-arrow solutions that I feel are more idiomatic as they use CoffeeScript's class syntax:

```
class AccountWithFatCallback
  constructor: (@customer, @cart) ->
    $('.shopping_cart').bind 'click', (event) =>
      @customer.purchase @cart

class AccountWithFatProtoMethod
  constructor: (@customer, @cart) ->
    $('.shopping_cart').bind 'click', @onClickCart
  onClickCart: => 
    @customer.purchase @cart
```

All of these were compiled using the latest CoffeeScript compiler, v1.8.0, and you can see the benchmark on [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/coffeescript-fat-thin-arrow-callbacks).  The performance difference between the four implementations was minimal (~5% or so), so I'd suggest that the determining factor of what to use should be readability and consistency of your codebase, but I'd strongly suggest you try using CoffeeScript classes as they've a lot to offer to that end.

The only performance caveat I'd raise is to avoid creating fat-arrow anonymous functions many times if you have the option of creating them once and re-using the same bound function.  Using fat-arrow prototype methods achieves this by implicitly binding the method once in the constructor.

Comment: Great answer! The performance difference between the four implementations was minimal, indeed.